# Issues regarding solr service

Tags: php, search, solr

I am facing an issue with `Solr 6.0.1` where I am trying to implement search functionality for my website . So later i followed up the instructions given in this [site](http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/how-to-add-search-with-solr/) . But now I am facing this error

```
Solr service is not available

 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''404' Status: Not Found' in /Users/Tanishq/Sites/SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php:338 Stack trace: #0 /Users/Tanishq/Sites/SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php(1209): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('http://localhos...') #1 /Users/Tanishq/Sites/results.php(16): Apache_Solr_Service->search('ok', 0, 10) #2 {main} thrown in /Users/Tanishq/Sites/SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php on line 338
```

Here are those lines from `service.php`

```
338:     throw new Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException($solrResponse);

1209: return $this->_sendRawGet($this->_searchUrl.$this->_queryDelimiter.$queryString);
```

and here is my code for `result.php`

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['query']) || empty($_REQUEST['query']))
   {
header('Location: http://localhost/~Tanishq/search.php ');
}
else
{
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
}
require_once('constants.php');
require_once('SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php');
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service(SOLRHOST, SOLRPORT, SOLRNAME);
     if( ! $solr->ping()) { 
        echo 'Solr service is not available'; 
    } 
$results = $solr->search($query, 0, 10);  

if(empty($results))
{
    echo "not available";
}
else echo "Displaying";
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th>' .
'<th>Name</th>' .
'<th>Description</th>' .
'<th>Price</th></tr>';
 {
  foreach($results->response->docs as $doc)
  {
      echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($doc->id).'</td>' .
           '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($doc->product_name).'</td>'.
           '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($doc->product_description).'</td>'.
           '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($doc->product_price).'</td></tr>';
}
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Please help me asap as i am in dire need for this search

Comment: What is the URL you're using for access Solr? Does it work in your browser? Is it hosted on the same server that your code runs on? Since you're getting a 404 error, it indicates that the request hits a non-existing URL.